# How to grep the result of a grep?

Tags: grep

I need to grep some files to see which ones contain a certain word:

```
grep -l word *
```

Next I need to grep that list of files to see which ones contain a different word. The easy way would probably be to write a script but I don't know quite how to work it.

Comment: Which `grep`? GNU `grep`? Are you on Linux, Solaris, the BSDs?

Comment: I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming none of the file names contain whitespace, single quote, double quote or backslash characters (or start with - with GNU `grep`), you can do:

```
grep -l word * | xargs grep word2
```

Xargs will run the second grep over each file from the first grep.

With GNU `grep`/`xargs` or compatible, you can make it more reliable with:

```
grep -lZ word ./* | xargs -r0 grep word2
```

Using `-Z` makes `grep` print the file names NUL-delimited so it can be used with `xargs -0`. The `-r` option to `xargs` avoids the second `grep` being run if the first `grep` doesn't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -l word1 $(grep -l word2 *)
```

or maybe for one of the two words on the same line:

```
grep -w 'word1\|word2' *
```

see [here](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to find files containing a word and then filter out those files containing another word, you could use a sequence of commands like this:

```
grep word * | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'|uniq | xargs grep word2
```

- `grep word *` - will show all files containing "word", the filename will be first in the list.
- `awk -F ':' '{print $1}'` - will print only the filename of your results
- `uniq` - will make sure that you do not print the filename more than once.
- `xargs grep word2` - will again search in the list of files you got.

Comment: @don_crissti But combining pieces `grep -l word1 * | xargs -d'\n' grep -l word2` works for anything except newline, which is weird enough almost nobody uses it.